# Gulp при добавление изображение в проект выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp

пытаюсь вставить изображение в папку проекта , как только добавляю файл jpg или png сразу Gulp начинает ругаться , помогите пожалуйста разобраться

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.
F:\Welcome\Gulp>gulp
[10:05:21] Using gulpfile F:\Welcome\Gulp\gulpfile.js
[10:05:21] Starting 'default'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'watchFiles'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'browserSync'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'clean'...
[10:05:21] Finished 'clean' after 127 ms
[10:05:21] Starting 'js'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'css'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'html'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'images'...
[10:05:21] Starting 'fonts'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.html)
[10:05:31] Finished 'html' after 10 s
[10:05:31] 'images' errored after 10 s
[10:05:31] Error in plugin "gulp-webp"
Message:
????? ?? ????? ???? ?????? ????.

Details:
errno: ENOENT
code: ENOENT
syscall: spawn F:\Welcome\Gulp\node_modules\cwebp-bin\vendor\cwebp.exe
killed: false
stdout:
stderr: ????? ?? ????? ???? ?????? ????.

failed: true
signal: null
cmd: F:\Welcome\Gulp\node_modules\cwebp-bin\vendor\cwebp.exe -quiet -mt -q 7
0 -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\a399bf55-3c5e-4fb4-9d85-790980ad6619 C:\Us
ers\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1fda3ab7-9377-4e93-a16d-451538b33ea7
timedOut: false
fileName: F:\Welcome\Gulp\src\img\slider2.png
domainEmitter: [object Object]
domainThrown: false

[10:05:31] 'default' errored after 10 s

F:\Welcome\Gulp>
```

настройки Gulp

```
    let project_folder = "dist";
    let source_folder = "src";
    let fs = require('fs');
    let path = {
    build: {
    html: project_folder + '/',
    css: project_folder + '/css/',
    js: project_folder + '/js/',
    img: project_folder + '/img/',
    fonts: project_folder + '/fonts/'
    },
    src: {
    html: [source_folder + '/*.html', "!" + source_folder + '/_*.html'],
    css: source_folder + '/scss/style.scss',
    js: source_folder + '/js/script.js',
    img: source_folder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}',
    fonts: source_folder + '/fonts/*.ttf'
     },
    watch: {
    html: source_folder + '/**/*.html',
    css: source_folder + '/scss/**/*.scss',
    js: source_folder + '/js/**/*.js',
    img: source_folder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}'

     },
     clean: './' + project_folder + '/'
     }
  let {
  src,
  dest
  } = require('gulp');
  let gulp = require('gulp');
  let browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();
  let fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
  let del = require('del');
  let scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
  let autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
  let group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries');
  let clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css');
  let rename = require('gulp-rename');
  let uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
  let imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
  let webp = require('gulp-webp');
  let webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html');
  let webpcss = require('gulp-webpcss');
  let svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite');
  let ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff');
  let ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2');
  let fonter = require('gulp-fonter');
  function browserSync(params) {
  browsersync.init({
  server: {
  baseDir: './' + project_folder + '/'
   },
 port: 3000,
  notify: false
  });
  }

  function html() {
  return src(path.src.html)
  .pipe(fileinclude())
  .pipe(webphtml())
  .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
  .pipe(browsersync.stream())
  };
  function images() {
  return src(path.src.img)
 .pipe(
  webp({
    quality: 70
  })
  )
.pipe(dest(path.build.img))
.pipe(src(path.src.img))
.pipe(
  imagemin({
    progressive: true,
    svgoPlugin: [{
      removeViewBox: false
    }],
    interlaced: true,
    optimizationLevel: 3
  })
)
.pipe(dest(path.build.img))
.pipe(browsersync.stream())
};


gulp.task('svgSprite', function () {
return gulp.src([source_folder + '/iconsprite/*.svg'])
.pipe(svgSprite({
  mode: {
    stack: {
      sprite: '../icons/icons.svg',
      example: true
     }
  }
}))
.pipe(dest(path.build.img))
});

function cb() {};

function watchFiles(param) {
gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean(param) {
return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts), fontsStyle);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.fontsStyle = fontsStyle;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```